# Automorphisms of order $2$ of the multiplicative group of a field

Tags: field-theory

Let $k$ be any field, finite or infinite, (even though I'm more interested in the infinite case) of $\operatorname{Char}(k)\neq2$. Let $\varphi$ be an automorphism **of order $2$** of the multiplicative group $k^\times$ of $k$ ($\varphi$ is **not** assumed to be a field automorphism). Assume further that $\varphi$ fixes precisely $2$ points: $\pm 1$.
The only example of such $\varphi$ that I have is $\varphi(x)=x^{-1}$.
Can anyone show another example of such $\varphi$?
Alternatively, can one show that those conditions force $\varphi$ to be the inverse?
**NB:** I came across this in my research (which is not exactly in the theory of fields), and I'm looking for conditions to force $\varphi$ to be the inverse.

Comment: If $\phi(r)=s$, then $\phi(s)=r$, and $\phi(rs)=rs$, so for every $r$, $\phi$ fixes $r\phi(r)$. So, for every $r$, $\phi(r)=\pm r^{-1}$. Doesn't settle matters, but it looks like progress.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson: Thanks - I looked before at $X=\{\varphi(r)r^{-1}|r\in k^\times\}$ and noticed that $k^\times/\{\pm1\}\cong X$. Since for $x\in X$ we have $\varphi(x)=x^{-1}$, this says that $\varphi$ indeed flips a lot of elements, but this way around seems more promissing.

Comment: So, take $k$ to be the rationals, where every nonzero element can be written uniquely as $\pm1p_1^{a_1}\times\cdots\times p_r^{a_r}$ for some primes $p_1,\dots,p_r$, and let $\phi(p)=-p^{-1}$ for each prime $p$ --- does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x \in k^\times$. Then $\phi(x\phi(x)) = \phi(x)\phi^2(x) = \phi(x)x = x\phi(x)$, so $x\phi(x)$ is a fixpoint of $\phi$. Under your assumption, you get $x\phi(x) = 1$ or $x\phi(x) = -1$.

So you get a group morphism $k^\times \to \{-1;+1\}$ given by $x \mapsto x\phi(x)$.
Its kernel is either $k^\times$ or a subgroup $H$ of index $2$ containing $-1$.

Conversely, for every subgroup $H$ of index $2$ of $k^\times/\{\pm 1\}$, there is a corresponding involution $\phi$ defined by $\phi(x) = 1/x$ for $x\in H$ and $\phi(x) = -1/x$ for $x\notin H$

For example, let $k = \Bbb Q$. $\Bbb Q^\times /\{\pm 1\} \cong \bigoplus_{p} \Bbb Z$ (where for prime $p$, $\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Q$ is given by $n \mapsto p^n$).
For example, for each prime $p$ there is the subgroup $H_p$ consisting of rationals whose $p$-valuation is even. It has index $2$ and contains $-1$, and they correspond to a non-trivial involution $\phi_p(x) = (-1)^{v_p(x)}/x$

Comment: +1: Thanks. This generalises the idea given by @Gerry Myerson.